# Stretching a line from a point in the xy-plane towards (x,y,z) point in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a line that starts from the (x,y,0) point in the xy-plane and ends at the (x,y,z) value.

Is this possible in matplotlib?

Here's an example of what I have:
[image]

versus what I want:
[image]

Here we have the dot at (1,1,1). So basically I want to know if it's possible to extend a line going from (1,1,0) in the xy-plane to (1,1,1) in 3D.

Hope my question is clear to understand with this example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This doesn't make any sense. If you're working in three dimensions, then every point can be described in three dimensions, including your starting point. Describing something with only two coordinates in three dimensional space is essentially describing a line; if you only explicitly label the x and y coordinates, then all possible z values are valid- so you end up with a line.

What you want to do is make one of the coordinates (x, y, or z) zero.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1[![enter image description here][1]][1]5,10))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# points
xs = np.asarray([np.cos(i) for i in np.arange(0,np.pi/2,(np.pi/2)/10)])
ys = np.arange(0,10,1)
zs = np.arange(0,10,1)

# plot points
ax.scatter(xs=xs, ys=ys, zs=zs, s=200, c=zs, cmap=cm.viridis_r, alpha=1.0)

# create the line
zs_l = np.asarray([[i, -1] for i in zs])

# color list
cl = [cm.get_cmap('viridis_r')(i/zs_l.shape[0]) for i in range(zs_l.shape[0])]
# draw the lines 
for i, p in enumerate(zs_l):
    ax.plot(xs=[xs[i]]*2, ys=[ys[i]]*2, zs=zs_l[i], markersize=0, lw=3, c=cl[i])
```

[image: Final plot.]