# How to create a 3d XYZ line plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, linear-algebra

I have been trying to create 3D XYZ Line Plot in Matplotlib and I have no idea how to create the negative axes and multiple lines starting from the origin.

I have looked through all the galleries and although there seem categories from line plots, most of them are 2-D or none showing multiple lines in the positive AND negative axis. I have done the math and here is the graph.

[3D Line Plot with Multiple Axes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Emac.jpg)

Here are the particular values for this one in the format(vector:[x,y]): x1: [1,1], x1':[1,-1], y1: [2,-1], y1': [-1,-2], z1: [-2,-3], z1':[-3,2]

This is my template code so far that I got off of an online website and I have been playing around with it.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

datasets = [{"x":[1,0,0], "y":[0,1,0], "z":[0,0,-1], "colour": "red"} for _ in range(6)]

for dataset in datasets:
    ax.plot(dataset["x"], dataset["y"], dataset["z"], color=dataset["colour"])

plt.show()
```

For the results I am looking for I end up getting just a singular line and have no idea how to create multiple ones splitting into several directions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stretching a line from a point in the xy-plane towards (x,y,z) point in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36227615/stretching-a-line-from-a-point-in-the-xy-plane-towards-x-y-z-point-in-matplotl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to draw several vectors from the origin to a specific xyz point. I would rewrite the format of your dataset to have a series of [x,y,z] coordinates for the end of each vector, then do:

```
datasets = {"x1": [1,2,-2], "x2":[1,-2,2], "x3":[3,-2,-2]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
for key,p in datasets.items():
    ax.plot([0,p[0]], [0,p[1]], [0,p[2]], label=key)

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]